# Open a file in a temp directory in Max/MSP standalone

Tags: unix, named-pipes, max-msp-jitter

I have a Max/MSP standalone that looks for an external folder when it opens (it contains JSON files generated by R), which it does with `loadbang` -> `prefix ~/folder_name`.

This works OK, but I don't want to store the folder in `home`.
What I really want is to use Terminal to tell my standalone where to look, something like:

```
open -a standalone.app /var/folders/whatevercrazytempdirname/folder_name
```

But this doesn't work. Maybe I could establish a pipe between the program that generates the folder (R) and my standalone, but I don't know that this is possible with a Max/MSP standalone, and I haven't been able to find anyone who has done this.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to acquire runtime arguments in a Max standalone.

Perhaps you can have R write a text file to a standard directory (for example ~/Library/Application Support/MaxAppName/) that contains the whatevercrazytempdir path? The Max app could take it form there..

Alternatively, if R were to support udp networking, you could send Max an OSC message with the path.

Comment: I'll take a look at the UDP option, but I'm coming to the same conclusion about runtime arguments. Seems like something they really should support, but perhaps there just isn't big demand for it.